# Como realizar package de uma aplicação Spring Boot com maven sem executar os testes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com o Spring Boot e toda vez que realizo o comando `mvn package` ele executa os meus testes unitários. Porém, meus testes não levantam o servidor com a aplicação para executar os testes nele, devido ao banco de dados não se encontra em minha máquina. Com isso, todos os testes geram erro e o *package* falha. Como posso executar o empacotamento sem executar os testes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples, basta realizar adicionar valor `true` a variável `maven.test.skip`. O comando fica assim:

```
mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```